# Display Widget in app Android

Tags: java, android, widget

I want to display a widget in my app, preferably mostly through the layout xml, but I can't find how to actually show a widget :S

Comment: Why is my question being marked down!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use App Widgets which are miniature application views that can be embedded in other applications (such as the Home screen) and receive periodic updates. These views are referred to as Widgets in the user interface, and you can publish one with an App Widget provider. An application component that is able to hold other App Widgets is called an App Widget host.

**To create an App Widget, you need the following:**

i)`AppWidgetProviderInfo` object, describes the metadata for an App Widget, such as the App Widget's layout, update frequency, and the AppWidgetProvider class. This should be defined in XML.
ii)`AppWidgetProvider` class implementation, defines the basic methods that allow you to programmatically interface with the App Widget, based on broadcast events. Through it, you will receive broadcasts when the App Widget is updated, enabled, disabled and deleted.
iii)View layout, defines the initial layout for the App Widget, defined in XML.
iv)Additionally, you can implement an App Widget configuration Activity. This is an optional Activity that launches when the user adds your App Widget and allows him or her to modify App Widget settings at create-time.

Please visit the following two links:

i) http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html
ii) http://www.techhive.com/article/259845/the-15-best-android-widgets.html

Comment: Thanks a lot all have a look later

Answer (score 0):

Here are some resources.

[App Widgets](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html)

[Android (Homescreen) Widgets - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidWidgets/article.html)